# Generic variable name mechanism in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm fairly new in javascript world and have a trouble with mechanism where I send variable name to function, that checks whether sent variable is set to true or not.

First of all I have got three variables:

```
variable: boolean = false;
variable1: boolean = false;
variable2: boolean = false;
```

And then from html view I call the function isChecked() this way:

```
isChecked('variable2')
```

and isChecked() function :

```
public isChecked(propName: string): boolean {
    return this.['propName'] == true; // but compiler here has an error, I dont know how to properly indicate to variable
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `this[propName]` instead of `this.['propName']`

Answer (score 0):

> public isChecked(propName: string): boolean {  return this['propName']
>   == true;
>    }